# On the minimal polynomial of the sum of two algebraic numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra

I was studying an algorithm to get the minimal polynomial of a constructible number and found out this answer (https://mathoverflow.net/a/211556/100740) with the following two assertions:

> "Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be two algebraic numbers over $\mathbb Q$ and suppose that $\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n$ and $\beta_1, ..., \beta_m$ are roots of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, respectively. Then, the polynomial
>   $$
> r(x)=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\prod_{j=1}^{m} (x-\alpha_i-\beta_j)
> $$
>   is in $\mathbb Q[x]$."

I can't see why the coefficients of $r(x)$ are rationals. I read that it has to do with the fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials, but no one really got into details of why this is true.

> Using elementary symmetric polynomials we can compute $r(x)$ without knowing the roots $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_j$.

I was also wondering why that is true.

Comment: Do you know Galois theory? $r(x)$ is fixed under any permutation in the Galois group of the splitting field of the product of the minimal polynomials of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, as any permutation must bijectively map the $\alpha_i$s among themselves and the $\beta_j$s among themselves. The polynomial has all possible pairs of products, so any permutation will just permute factors, so it is fixed, meaning every coefficient belongs to the ground field $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: The coefficients of $\prod_i (x-\alpha_i)$ are elementary symmetric polynomials in $\alpha_i$ and obviously rational. Therefore, any symmetric polynomial in $\alpha_i$ (or $\beta_j$) lies in $\mathbb{Q}$. Taking the inner product in $r(x)$ gives you a polynomial in $x-\alpha_i$ whose coefficients are symmetric polynomials in $\beta_j$, so they lie $\mathbb{Q}$. Then taking the outer product gives you a symmetric polynomial in $x-\alpha_i$, whose coefficients again lie in $\mathbb{Q}$ by the same reasoning. If you feel uneasy about this argument, try and work out the case $m=n=2$.

Comment: Ok. Now I got it. But, what about some method to compute $r(x)$ without knowing the roots?